# How can you get the j first most significant bits of an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, bit

I know that to get the first j least significant bits of an integer you can do the following:

```
  int res = (myInteger & ((1<<j)-1))
```

Can you do something similar for the most significant bits?

Comment: Do you understand what the least-significant code does? If yes, where´s the problem? An int has `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)` bit

Comment: note to anyone including `1 <<` in their answer: make sure the `1` is cast (or suffixed) to be unsigned and wide enough for the length of shift you're doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply right shift:  (Warning, fails when you want 0 bits, but yours fails for all bits)

```
unsigned dropbits = CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-j;
//if you want the high bits moved to low bit position, use this:
ullong res = (ullong)myInteger >> dropbits; 
//if you want the high bits in the origonal position, use this:
ullong res = (ullong)myInteger >> dropbits << dropbits;
```

## Important! The cast must be the *unsigned version of your type*.

It's also good to note that your code for the lowest `j` bits fails when you ask it for all (32?) bits.  As such, it can be easier to doubleshift:

```
unsigned dropbits = CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-j;
ullong res = (ullong)myInteger << dropbits >> dropbits;
```

See it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64eb843b3b255278 and here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29bc40188d852dd3

Comment: is (ullong)myInteger << dropbits >> dropbits; right?  << and >> are the same order of precedence.  execution happens from left to right.  does that give you what you want?

Comment: @thang: I tested, it gets executed in the correct order.  The goal is to shift left so the processor drops the high bits, then shift right to bring them back to the original places.  It must be unsigned or else when the processor shifts right it will fill the high bits with ones instead of zeroes.

Comment: woops, change to drop_for_low = 16 and myInteger = 0x12340000.  what happens?  is that right?  the right result is 0x12340000.

Comment: you've got to be f'-ing kidding me.  Your result is 0!  It's wrong.  How much hand holding do I need to do?

Comment: ok, I apologize in advance, but you're a f'en idiot.  sizeof(unsigned) = sizeof(int) = 4.  The top 16 bits of 0x12340000 is 0x1234, not 0.  In what world is taking the top 16 bit of 0x12340000 become 0?

Comment: (ullong)myInteger << dropbits >> dropbits should be myInteger >> dropbits << dropbits and if you are a coder with any sense of decency for the guy coming after you, you'd write it as this (myInteger >> dropbits) << dropbits.  I cannot believe it takes that many comments for you to not even get it.

Comment: @thang: You're totally right, that comment was 100% wrong.  I temporarily was thinking 1hex=1byte.  My bad.  However, code and reasoning is still right, you probably forgot to cast to the unsigned version of the input type: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec61070e367363c

Comment: @thang: Wait, you just quoted the code that gives the _low bits_.  No wonder you're so confused!  (In both cases, parenthesis are unnecessary, but can be added if you feel like it)

Answer (score 2):

To get the `j` highest bits of an integer (or rather an unsigned integer, because bitwise operations in signed integers are a recipe for pain):

```
unsigned res = myUnsignedInteger & ~(~0u >> j);
```

`~0u` consists of only set bits. Shifting that `j` bits to the right gives us `j` zero-bits on the left side followed by one-bits, and inverting that gives us `j` one-bits on the left followed by zeroes, which is the mask we need to isolate the `j` highest bits of another integer.

Note: This is under the assumption that you want the isolated bits to remain in the same place, which is to say

```
(0xdeadbeef & ~(~0u >> 12)) == 0xdea00000
```

Comment: It's implementation defined if `-1u` has all bits set or not.  However, `~0u` always has all bits set.